# More button is moving down in the chrome browser

Tags: css, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on a prestashop theme and the more button is moving down in the chrome browser but it renders fine in firefox.

http://bit.ly/1pzlXoW

**CHROME SCREENSHOT** More button should be on the same line like in firefox browser. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ebfhbq&s=8#.U2xnv_mSyB8

Chrome version - Version 34.0.1847.131 m
Firefox Version - 28.0

Thanks

Comment: Specify the version of chrome you are using and add a image to help us understand how it renders on your browser. It looks fine on my chrome 34.0.1847.131

Comment: More button should be on the same line FIREFOX SCREEN http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23vhzi8&s=8#.U2xnc_mSyB8

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, AND in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: Hi KatieK Sorry I didn't get you? you want me to paste all the codes? also this is not a JavaScript problem I think its an Issue with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The 'More' button displays fine in my browser.

Make sure you've got the most recent version of Chrome.

Comment: Tx Jonathan Is it showing same as firefox? can you send me a screenshot please if you don't mind? Becouse I have the latest version Version 34.0.1847.131 m. FIRE FOX - Screen shot http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23vhzi8&s=8#.U2xnc_mSyB8                                 Chrome screen shot - http://tinypic.com/r/2ebfhbq/8